# error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do something in javascript, but it give me an error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

This is the code:

`<img src='upvote-normal.png' onclick='vote('upvote', 1);' style='width: 50px'>`

Please help me :(

Comment: nested quotes 101...  open quote --> `'vote('` <-- closing quote  so your code looks like `<img src="upvote-normal.png" onclick="vote(" upvote',="" 1);'="" style="width: 50px">` I'm too lazy to find a dupe.

Comment: Did you closed the tag? `<img src='upvote-normal.png' onclick='vote('upvote', 1);' style='width: 50px'/>` or `<img src='upvote-normal.png' onclick='vote('upvote', 1);' style='width: 50px'></img>`

Comment: @Elias error has nothing to do with that

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your quotes like this:

`<img src='upvote-normal.png' onclick='vote("upvote", 1);' style='width: 50px'>`

or this:

`<img src="upvote-normal.png" onclick="vote('upvote', 1);" style="width: 50px">`

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to -

```
<img src='upvote-normal.png' onclick='vote("upvote", 1);' style='width: 50px'>
```

Comment: Explain why..... "Change your code to" does not tell the poster anything about why they got the error.

Comment: There is issue with the nested quotes.

Comment: So say that in your answer..... I am just trying to help you answer questions better here so you get upvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the help @epascarello